# sql for each record join on same table excluding the source record and get the max record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Budgets` table that contains columns:

```
Id, ProjectCode, CreatedDate, IsReest, etc..
```

I have to find the records IsReest=1 in the Budgets table and for each matching projectcode I have to get the max(createddate), but excluding IsReest=1 record.

I need  Id, ProjectCode, CreatedDate in the results as I need Id to join with other tables and ProjectCode and CreatedDate to display in the results.

So for example:
(I have used | delimiter to separate the values in the below tables)

```
Id  | ProjectCode   | CreatedDate | IsReest
------------------------------------------
 1  | 12345         | 2016-10-16  |    1
 2  | 12345         | 2016-10-14  |   NULL
 3  | 12222         | 2016-09-16  |   NULL
 4  | 12345         | 2016-10-15  |   NULL
 5  | 12333         | 2016-10-14  |   NULL
 6  | 12333         | 2016-10-15  |    1
```

Here records with Ids 1 and 6 has IsReest=1. I have to get max(CreatedDate) record for the same ProjectCode exluding IsReest=1 record.

So I have to get the results as:

```
Id | ProjectCode | CreatedDate | IsReset
-----------------------------------------
 4 | 12345       | 2016-10-15  |  NULL
 5 | 12333       | 2016-10-14  |  NULL
```

Record with ProjectCode 12222 should be ignored as it doesn't have a record with IsRest=1.

And record with Id 4 has the max(CreatedDate) in the group of records with the same ProjectCode and IsReest<>1.

Could some one please help me writing this query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @Table table(ID int, ProjectCode int, CreateDate date, IsReest int)
insert into @Table Values
       (1, 12345, '2016-10-16'  ,    1)
      ,(2, 12345, '2016-10-14'  ,   NULL)
      ,(3, 12222, '2016-09-16'  ,   NULL)
      ,(4, 12345, '2016-10-15'  ,   NULL)
      ,(5, 12333, '2016-10-14'  ,   NULL)
      ,(6, 12333, '2016-10-15'  ,    1)

;WITH FLTR AS(
    SELECT ProjectCode
    FROM @Table
    WHERE IsReest=1
)
, MX AS(
    SELECT     a.ProjectCode, MAX(a.CreateDate) AS CreateDate
    FROM       @Table as a
    INNER JOIN FLTR as b on a.ProjectCode=b.ProjectCode
    WHERE      a.IsReest IS NULL
    GROUP BY   a.ProjectCode
)
    SELECT a.*
    FROM @Table AS A
    INNER JOIN MX as b on a.ProjectCode=b.ProjectCode and a.CreateDate=b.CreateDate
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. But, it doesn't get the right results.. its not excluding the IsReest=1 records, instead its getting only IsReest=1 records.

Answer (score 0):

It works using the below query. It may not be the best solution, but it works perfectly.

declare @Table table(ID int, ProjectCode int, CreateDate date, IsReest int)
insert into @Table Values
(1, 12345, '2016-10-16'  ,    1)
,(2, 12345, '2016-10-14'  ,   NULL)
,(3, 12222, '2016-09-16'  ,   NULL)
,(4, 12345, '2016-10-15'  ,   NULL)
,(5, 12333, '2016-10-14'  ,   NULL)
,(6, 12333, '2016-10-15'  ,    1)

select * from @Table t join 
(
select projectcode, max(CreateDate) as CreateDate_Max from @Table where ProjectCode in 
(
select ProjectCode from @Table bb where bb.IsReest = 1
) and IsReest is NULL
group by projectcode
) b
on b.projectcode = t.ProjectCode and b.CreateDate_Max = t.CreateDate